# dynamic binding in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a class Topic and Group which both have a variable called 'name', so I am trying to combine these two if statements into one:

```
if ([((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) _item).object isKindOfClass:[Group class]]){
        Group * group = (Group *)(((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) self.object).object);
       //blah
    } else if ([((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) _item).object isKindOfClass:[Topic class]]){
        Topic * topic = (Topic *)(((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) self.object).object);
       //blah
    }
```

I tried

```
id group = (((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) self.object).object);
```

but when I tried group.name, it gives me:

property name not found on object of type id

Comment: Sigh.. another victim of "dot-syntax-is-the-same-as-message-sending-except-when-it-isn't"...

Comment: Purposeful design decision carefully considered that has largely helped with code quality.  In this case, the real problem is the lack of either an abstract base class or, less favorable, the use of an protocol.  Relying on (id) or typecasting leads to fragile, buggy, code.  The real issue is the ongoing meme that dot syntax is required to use properties and vice-versa.

Comment: trust me, if I can do it via an abstract base class.. I'd do it that way, rather than something dirty like this. It's a really long story why I can't do abstraction here, has to do with a framework I am working with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Objective-C, properties do undergo a stricter type checking at compile time.

You might want to try:

```
[group name];
```

What you do in this case is not using the property mechanism and sending a message to the object. This allow you to fully exploit the dynamic nature of Objective-C.

In this case, you will get a warning, but if you can stand it, it should work fine.

Comment: What warning does it give? It shouldn't give any warning as long as you've imported a header that declares a method with that selector and the correct signature.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a selector to test if an object implements a method before calling that method on the object.

```
SEL method = @selector(name:);
id groupOrTopic = [((RKMappableObjectTableItem *) self.object) object];

if ([groupOrTopic respondsToSelector:method])
    [groupOrTopic name];
```

I would not recommend using a base class for both of these objects, I would recommend defining a protocol and having both of these objects implement that protocol if you choose to got that route.

```
@protocol SomeProtocol
  -(NSString*)name;
@end
```

Comment: Using a protocol will work, but is a bit complex compared to just declaring an abstract base class that both Topic and Group inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is correct, `group` *does not* have a property called `name`. `group` is of type `id` and not `Topic` or `Group`.

Three options:

1. Cast it
2. Avoid using dot notation: `[group name]`
3. Have a base class common to both `Topic` and `Group` that has the `name` property

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with this way of describing things. The variable does not have properties at all, regardless of its type. You can't have a variable of type `Topic` or `Group` — only pointers. I think it's more accurate to say that the variable didn't carry enough information to determine the object's properties.